# Need recommendations on techniques or designs for this type of web site?

Tags: database, programming-languages, dynamic, real-time

So, I've just decided to build my own fantasy sports web site.

You know the type of site where you can pick players from your favourite league and depending on how they do you get a certain amount of points in your team. There are fantasy teams for all types of leagues and sports, I'm sure you know what I'm talking about.
I haven't settled for a specific sport or league just yet because I want the basics to fit to different types of team-based sports.

I have a few expectations on it myself. If you can come up with any other I'll be glad to hear them.

- I expect the site to be dynamic and have many visits during a game, but almost only static content otherwise.
- Player points should be updated in real-time during a game.
- I would need a list that shows each game being played and the points of every player in that game. It should also show minutes played, goals, assists etc.
- Each registered user would be able to see the points and players of his/hers team updated in real time.
- I need the site to scale so that if I start with 1000 teams I could end up with 5 million.
- I probably won't be needing language support right now, but who knows in the future.

Based on these prerequisites what would be best to use in terms of language (php, .NET, drupal or other cms's), database (mysql, sqlserver, xml) and other techniques?
Maybe it doesn't really matter what I use?

I guess the dynamic and real time update of each player's points is where I need help the most.

Thanks in advance!

/Niklas

**EDITED**
I could use an array with the following data for a specific game week:

- Player ID
- Minutes played
- Sport specific points(goals, assists, penalties, yellow cards, man of the match bonus) etc.
- Total points in current game week

When the game is over I'd add these to a DB and sum this data with any previous game weeks. Plus player value, number of teams that has selected this player, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably going to have to go down the custom route for your "Game" code - rather than using a CMS, although depending on your experience, you may be able to leverage a framework (e.g CodeIgniter) to speed up some of your DEV time.
This type of site would be pretty language agnostic, however it would depend on the actual numbers of users you are looking at as to the most scalable solution / set of techniques to deploy.

One of the biggest considerations you are going to have to look at would be the design of the data model, and the platform that this sits on.

If you want to be processing near to realtime updates, you are going to want to focus your efforts on making the DB queries / processing the most efficient possible.

Comment: That's why I'm leaning towards using XML. Since the only real dynamic data are the points on each player it would seem unnecessary to query a DB every time. Wouldn't an XML file be faster to query in this aspect?  Or maybe even use something like .Net's Cache. There isn't really that much dynamic data to be stored.

Comment: It all depends, what data you would be storing, how big the XML is, how you will be traversing the XML doc etc. A well tuned DB, with caching implemented can be just as good. The other thing to ask is - OK you need to scale, but being realistic how many users are you expecting?

Comment: In my dreams I'm expecting 100k users, but who knows. Also, a league would probably have 15-30 teams with at most 40 players each, which makes about 1k players to update. But all games are not played at once so at most 600 players to update every minute.

Comment: Ok so in volume terms 600 "on-line" users isn't huge, if you had come back and said 100,000 online users then there is more than a worry. I would personally focus on getting your "game" working, with a decent data model. If and when your site grows, providing your design was good in the first place it should be easy to scale.

Comment: *"if you had come back and said 100,000 online users"* That's what I said? I said there may be 600 players, that is hockey or football players that need to be updated.

Comment: by online i mean concurrent, apologies. Your numbers are still very low to be too concerned about.

Answer (score 0):

One big consideration that you have not discussed here is caching. There is some data on your site that I am sure will be static for long periods of time (such as weekly totals etc), and there is data that will be very much real time (but only during match days).

However, during match days you will have a lot more traffic than non match days, and you will therefore have a lot of requests for the same data in a short period of time. Therefore, employing a good caching strategy will save you masses of CPU power. What I am thinking of, is to calculate a player's score and then cache for 1 minute at a time, therefore each time that specific player is requested, you are retrieving from a cache, rather than recalculating each time.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned something like this in the comments of diagonalbatman's answer. I might not even have to use a database at all since there isn't that much dynamic data to be stored and processed.